# MySQLi - Server returned unknown type 246

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working on a content managed site that's been working fine on localhost. I've just uploaded the files to my mediatemple server.. and am seeing some pretty interesting results:

**Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Server returned unknown type 246. Probably your client library is incompatible with the server version you use!**

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before. I'm completely stumped! Works great on localhost (MAMP), but breaks on the live server :-(.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.0.3, a new field type was introduced, to support fixed-point math with more accuracy.  This new field type is identified in the MySQL protocol with a numeric value 246.

If you have a MySQL server running 5.0.x or higher, and you use the `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`, it's incompatible with the `DECIMAL` field type used in the MySQL 4.x client.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html says:

> Because the MySQL 5.0 server has a new implementation of the `DECIMAL` data type, a problem may occur if the server is used by older clients that still are linked against MySQL 4.1 client libraries. If a client uses the binary client/server protocol to execute prepared statements that generate result sets containing numeric values, an error will be raised: `'Using unsupported buffer type: 246'`
>
> This error occurs because the 4.1 client libraries do not support the new `MYSQL_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL` type value added in 5.0. There is no way to disable the new `DECIMAL` data type on the server side. You can avoid the problem by relinking the application with the client libraries from MySQL 5.0.

Also see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35536

You should be able to resolve this issue by upgrading your MySQL client library in PHP.  Either rebuild PHP, or else just drop in a new MySQL client binary.

Best of all would be to use the newer **[mysqlnd](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/)** library, which gives you a lot of benefits to performance and functionality.  That library is included in the source distribution of PHP 5.3 and later.  It states in the FAQ that it *requires* PHP 5.3, which actually surprises me, but that's what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Change your DECIMAL type to FLOAT in the database until it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a MySQL version problem.

This is what I found in another forum:

```
apt-get source php5-mysqli
cd php5-...
./configure --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config --without-mysql
make
cp ext/mysqli/modules/mysqli.so /usr/lib/php5/...
```

Obviously you probably have different folder names, but I hope you get the idea.