# java.sql.SQLException: Unknown type '246 in column 10 of 12 in binary-encoded re sult set

Tags: java, mysql, windows, tomcat, jdbc

When I start Tomcat on Windows, I receive the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown type '246' in column 10 of 12 in binary-encoded result set.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.extractNativeEncodedColumn(MysqlIO.ja‌​va:3710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackBinaryResultSetRow(MysqlIO.java‌​:3620)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1282)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:413)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.j‌​ava:1899)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerP‌​reparedSt atement.java:1393)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(Serve‌​rPrepared Statement.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatem‌​ent.java:1705)
```

I am using the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21` JDBC driver.

I have deployed my app in Tomcat as a `war`. I use both normal and prepared statements.

Comment: We need to see the complete stack trace and the source code it points to.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown type '246 in column 10 of 12 in binary-encoded re
sult set.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.extractNativeEncodedColumn(MysqlIO.java:3710)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackBinaryResultSetRow(MysqlIO.java:3620)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1282)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2198)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:413)

Comment: at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:1899)

        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1347)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedSt
atement.java:1393)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPrepared
Statement.java:958)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:
1705)

Comment: please find the above complete stacktrace.

Comment: Put it in the question, (properly formatted,) please.

Comment: @satish , can you give your MySQL JDBC Driver version please.

Comment: @rjdkolb please find the MySQL connection version "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21"

Answer (score 1):

This may be a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14609

According to that bug tracker, an attempt to fix it was made for versions 5.0.1 and 3.1.13 *of the JDBC driver* (not on server side), and it might not be a full fix.

Also see [MySQLi - Server returned unknown type 246](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786654/mysqli-server-returned-unknown-type-246)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar kind of issue: `java.sql.SQLException: Unknown type '245 in column 6 of 10 in binary-encoded result set.` I got this when I was making a REST call to a Dao using JDBI to fetch result-set based on some criteria (Query: `SELECT * FROM entity WHERE id = :Id`). Entity had a JSON column and I was using outdated `mysql-connector-java` version. Updating it from `5.1.27` to `8.0.28` resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when your application expects a certain datatype, but you receive another type from the database. E.g. you expect a `double`, but the database gives you an `int`.

You should check the type you are expecting.