# Error 245 in mysql prepare

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, macos

I am trying to get a database to work for my app where I want to save results in a database. I have set up a set of php-files which I call from my android application. Everything works as long as the table does not have any columns with json data, but I want to save a json file in my database. The error I get is

```
mysqli::prepare(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers in      <b>/Users/usrname/LearnPhP/Documents/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
```

Line 59 in DB_Functions:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
```

I have googled but not found anything. I am working on my MacBook, when using Windows 10 it works perfectly. However, it should work on Mac as well, secondly the next step is to set up a server which is on my desktop computer and then I need to work from my Mac to test it properly.

SOLUTION:

Thanks to the tip in the comments I found out that there was a mismatch between php and mysql. I have mysql 5.7.12 and now I use php 7 and that works fine.

I followed [this](https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-multiple-php-versions) to update my php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786654/mysqli-server-returned-unknown-type-246

Comment: Well that is an error 246, not 245 but I can try upgrading mysql in php.

Comment: I think JSON is supported only mysql >= 5.7 so it might be a mismatch with versions.

Comment: what's your mysql version ?

Comment: 5.7.12, but now I use php 70 and that works fine